# Display full camera in iPad

Tags: objective-c

I am try to display full camera in iPad. but it displays very small camera. I am using below this code.

```
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.delegate=self;
    imagePicker.cameraOverlayView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 700);
    [imagePicker.cameraOverlayView sizeToFit];
    UIPopoverController  *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
    imagePicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    [imagePicker release];
                [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0,0,400,800) 
                                 inView:self.view
               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                               animated:YES];
```

Comment: Deserving -1 for no caps, cry for urgent help and leaving thread unaccepted nor discussed.

Answer (score 10):

`UIImagePickerController` is a `UINavigationController`. Just show it as a full screen modal view controller instead of in a popover.

```
UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
ipc.delegate = self;
ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
ipc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

[self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You only need to use a popover on the iPad for selecting images from the photo library. But the camera is allowed to be shown full screen without a popover.